# How can I optimize this SQL query with 100.000 records?

Tags: mysql

There is my SQL query. Table system_mailer is for logging sent e-mails. When i want to search some data, query is 10 seconds long. It is possible on any way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM `system_mailer` 
WHERE `group` = 'selling_center' 
  AND `group_parameter_1` = '1' 
  AND `group_parameter_2` = '2138'
```

Timins is around couple of seconds, how could it be optimised?

Comment: Do you have a composite index on group, group_parameter_1, and group_Parameter 2?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following index on 4 columns would help performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON system_mailer (`group`, group_parameter_1, group_parameter_2, ID);
```

MySQL should be able to use this index on your current query.  By the way, if you are using InnoDB, and `ID` is the primary key, then you might be able to drop it from the explicit index definition, and just use this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON system_mailer (`group`, group_parameter_1, group_parameter_2);
```

Please avoid naming your columns and tables with reserved MySQL keywords like `group`.  Because you made this design decision, you will now be forced to forever escape that column name with backticks (ugly).

Comment: Topicstarter before blindy making this multiple column index.. i advice you to calculate index selectivity first of all columns..  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `group`)  / COUNT(table_total ) as group_selectivity, COUNT(DISTINCT `group_parameter_1`)  / COUNT(table_total ) as group_parameter_1_selectivity, ... FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS table_total FROM table) AS a`.. And place the column which is closest to `1` first in the index and place the least selective one last in the index.. As the most selective as the first item in the multiple column index the more records will be filterd.

Comment: @RaymondNijland In addition to your points, it's also possibly that cardinality would preclude the possibility of MySQL using this index altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
just be sure you have a composite index on  table  system_mailer  for the columns  

          (`group`, `group_parameter_1`, `group_parameter_2`)
```

and you can use redudancy adding the id to index  for avoid  data table access in query

```
          (`group`, `group_parameter_1`, `group_parameter_2`, ID)
```

Comment: Topicstarter before blindy making this multiple column index.. i advice you to calculate index selectivity first of all columns..  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `group`)  / COUNT(table_total ) as group_selectivity, COUNT(DISTINCT `group_parameter_1`)  / COUNT(table_total ) as group_parameter_1_selectivity, ... FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS table_total FROM table) AS a`.. And place the column which is closest to `1` first in the index and place the least selective one last in the index.. As the most selective as the first item in the multiple column index the more records will be filterd.

Comment: @RaymondNijland; that would also depend if each of those values is always included.  Say if GROUP is guaranteed along with Parameter_1, but not paramater_2; then those two should be first regardless if group_paramater_2 is closest to 0 right?  That way the index can be used by the most queries and not just this specific one. (you started this topic :P)

Comment: *"that would also depend if each of those values is always included. Say if GROUP is guaranteed along with Parameter_1, but not paramater_2; then those two should be first regardless if "* Yes @xQbert most likely you would need to make a [Histogram](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) in MySQL 8,0 for better index stats and better query plan, in those cases